# Importing excel dates into mysql coming up with 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql

I created a script to create a table and load the dates as needed, but they are still coming up wrong. Can anyone tell me whats wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE 
Data 
( Date date, 
 Day VARCHAR(10),
 Hour INT(3),
 Volume INT(6), 
 Speed INT(3),
 PRIMARY KEY (Date, Hour)
);

 Load Data INFILE 'D:/php/php2/I71N.csv'
 INTO TABLE Data
 fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n'
 (@var,Day,Hour,Volume,Speed)
 SET Date = STR_TO_DATE(@var, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Comment: What format are the excel dates?

Comment: They are 1/1/2008, i figured out why the original was code was not working i had already exported the file as the correct date mask yyyy-MM-dd, which for some reason it did not like, but now when they import its adding volume to the end of date. like so 2008-01-28-299 for example. Not sure why its doing that, and its causing primary key duplicates.

Comment: Ok guys i figured it out and i feel really stupid, when i re exported the file their was headers in it, and that caused the 2008-01-28-299 problem now the file is loading properly. Still dont get why if its in the same format it wont run but its all working now

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change your date to the mysql date format to yyyy-MM-dd.